# Individual sampling weights and percentages

Tags: stata, survey, weighted-sampling

I am working with public use microdata measuring educational attainment. I want to calculate the percentage of the population older than 25. I am merely unaware of how to use my individual weights when calculating this, or if I even have to.

I am wondering if using weights is necessary, and if so, can I use them simply by using the `egen percents` command?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Seth-C. Since this is apparently a software-specific question, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my `epctile` package. Type

```
findit epctile
```

in Stata. It supports `svyset`tings, which you would need to specify according to the study documentation.